# How can I detect when player cancels Google Play Games sign-in?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games

I'm using Unity.

I'm trying to detect when the player cancels the automatic Google Play Games sign-in, so I can disable automatic sign-in attempts whenever they play the game at a later date.

I need to do this to comply with the Quality Checklist, described here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist#1_sign-in

However, I can't find a way to determine the result of Social.localUser.Authenticate. I can only get a success true/false.

I need to see the resulting GP_ConnectionResultCode.

Here's my code for the authentication process, which gets called when the game starts. The problem is that "resultCode" never gets set, so it always returns the default value "SUCCESS" even though the code runs through the failure logic.

```
   public static GP_ConnectionResultCode resultCode;

   public void SignIn() {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log("Google Play Games sign-in success.");
            uScriptCustomEvent.BroadcastCustomEvent("SocialSignedIn", true, gameObject);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SocialAutoSignIn", 1);
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log ("Result code: " + resultCode);
            if (resultCode == GP_ConnectionResultCode.CANCELED) {
                Debug.Log("Google Play Games sign-in cancelled.");
                uScriptCustomEvent.BroadcastCustomEvent("SocialSignedIn", false, gameObject);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SocialAutoSignIn", 0);
            }
            else {
                Debug.Log("Google Play Games sign-in failed.");
                uScriptCustomEvent.BroadcastCustomEvent("SocialSignedIn", false, gameObject);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SocialAutoSignIn", 1);
            }
        }
    });
    #endif
   }
```

Any ideas? I've had a poke around but can't find many others having the same issue.

I did find this: http://answers.unity3d.com/question...ay-games-popup-if-user-denies.html?sort=votes
But that looks like it will assume the sign-in was cancelled even if it failed for any other reason.

Comment: purely FWIW.  many projects use the popular Prime31 plugins to handle PlayGame (and indeed GameCenter). it's trivial to handle that issue, with the P31 plugin.